# ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found as expected SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Message seen: ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found as expected

Executing: SELECT *,CASEWHEN ROW_NUMBER()......

The code to be executed is as below:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TICK_NO ORDER BY TICK_NO) > 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE PROFIT 
    END AS PROFIT,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TICK_NO ORDER BY TICK_NO) > 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE DEAL 
    END AS DEAL,
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TICK_NO ORDER BY TICK_NO) > 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE CONTRA 
    END AS CONTRA
FROM CTE;
```

Hope I can get more advise here. Thank you all!

Comment: `SELECT CTE.*, other_columns FROM CTE;`